# .Net WinForms Unexpected behaviour suspending layout of form with SendMessage(...WM_SETREDRAW..) when it has AllowTransparency=true, hides form

Tags: winforms, transparency, sendmessage

Having a form with:

```
Me.AllowTransparency = True
Me.BackColor = Color.Magenta
Me.TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor
```

And doing:

```
SendMessage(pForm.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, New IntPtr(CInt(False)), IntPtr.Zero)
```

Hides the form, without the transparency effect, works fine…

Is there a workaround? Another way to really suspend layout?

Definitions:

```
Private Const WM_SETREDRAW As Int32 = &HB
Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
```

Using Win10 (1803).

Comment: I see it.  The Windows version is important, Win10 Fall Creator's is pretty flaky with deep changes in the legacy winapi.  A workaround is to dock-fill a panel on the form and use it instead to do the painting and host controls, WM_SETREDRAW on that panel's handle doesn't go wrong.  And do consider SuspendLayout() to suspend layout, not the same thing as WM_SETREDRAW.

Comment: I'm using Win10 (1803).

Comment: Yeah, that one.  Best to put it in your question.

Comment: SuspendLayout() is not good enough, it shows some flicker's and it doesn't really suspend's the forms…
I tried your workaround and it worked! Thanks! 
The only drawback it that i need to place a panel in all my forms as a background panel.

Comment: Is there another workaround? I tried to put the panel in my base form, but all, but all controls in all descendant forms aren't automatically added to the new panel's controls array… They are still going to the form's controls array… I need to go to each one and change it manually..

Comment: That should not take more than a minute.  You probably haven't found the View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline window yet.  Drag+drop to give the control another panel.